# Add the first item to my listbox if empty vba

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have a userform with a 'search' listbox and a 'results' listbox. If I first import data into the results listbox ' lstresults ' from another array my code works and I can import individual items from ' lstsearch ' and it shows a new item in 'lstresults'.

When the lstresults is empty though before attempting to add data I can see the data has been added in my watch to a list variable in results but it is not visible in the lstresults. I have fiddled with various elements of the code but I must be missing something. Any help appreciated:

```
Private Sub cmdAddPlant_Click()

' Need to take data from selected line item from search box
' Add item to results list

lstResults.Visible = True
Dim ctlsource As Control

Dim plnt As Integer

Set ctlsource = Me!lstSearch

For plnt = 0 To ctlsource.ListCount - 2
    If ctlsource.Selected(plnt) = True Then
        
        With Me.lstResults.List
        
            If lstResults.ListCount > 0 Then _

            Me.lstResults.AddItem
            Me.lstResults.List(lstResults.ListCount - 1, 0) = lstSearch.List(plnt, 0)
            Me.lstResults.List(lstResults.ListCount - 1, 1) = lstSearch.List(plnt, 1)
            Me.lstResults.List(lstResults.ListCount - 1, 3) = lstSearch.List(plnt, 2)
            Me.lstResults.List(lstResults.ListCount - 1, 2) = lstSearch.List(plnt, 3)
                            
            Else
            ' I added this to try and deal with the first item but no dice
            lstResults.AddItem
            lstResults.List(0, 0) = lstSearch.List(plnt, 0)
            lstResults.List(0, 1) = lstSearch.List(plnt, 1)
            lstResults.List(0, 3) = lstSearch.List(plnt, 2)
            lstResults.List(0, 2) = lstSearch.List(plnt, 3)
            
            End If
            
        End With
        
        lstSearch.RemoveItem (plnt) ' Avoids accidently selecting plant twice
    
    End If

Next plnt
    
With lstResults

    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim sTemp2 As String
    Dim LbList As Variant

    'Store the list in an array for sorting
    LbList = Me.lstResults.List
    
    If UBound(LbList) > 1 Then
    'Bubble sort the array on the first value
    For i = LBound(LbList, 1) To UBound(LbList, 1) - 1
        For j = i + 1 To UBound(LbList, 1)
            If LbList(i, 0) > LbList(j, 0) Then
                'Swap the first value
                sTemp = LbList(i, 0)
                LbList(i, 0) = LbList(j, 0)
                LbList(j, 0) = sTemp
                'Swap the other values
                sTemp2 = LbList(i, 1)
                LbList(i, 1) = LbList(j, 1)
                LbList(j, 1) = sTemp2
                sTemp3 = LbList(i, 2)
                LbList(i, 2) = LbList(j, 2)
                LbList(j, 2) = sTemp3
                sTemp4 = LbList(i, 3)
                LbList(i, 3) = LbList(j, 3)
                LbList(j, 3) = sTemp4
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    'Remove the contents of the listbox
    lstResults.Clear
    'Repopulate with the sorted list
    lstResults.List = LbList
    End If

End With
Set LbList = Nothing
```

End Sub

Thanks - pic of screen to help you visualize....

[Userform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFEfN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work regardless of whether or not the list is empty

```vb
   Dim i As Long
    
    With lstResults
        .AddItem lstSearch.List(plnt, 0)
        i = .ListCount - 1
        .List(i, 1) = lstSearch.List(plnt, 1)
        .List(i, 2) = lstSearch.List(plnt, 2)
        .List(i, 3) = lstSearch.List(plnt, 3)
    End With
```